# Convert Javascript app into Windows app

Tags: javascript

Is there any solutions except Adobe Air? 
I have heard that V8 kinda have something there.

Just don't have time for now, to write on another language whole app and then write 2x more code.

Comment: Do you need access to the filesystem?

Comment: Yes and everything else aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use jsc: [Compiling JScript Code from the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7435xtz6(VS.71).aspx).

But you will have to replace browser-related objects by WinForms objects, which involves learning a new API, or use the [.NET WebBrowser object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) (a browser widget showing only the content of a page, without bars except scrollbars) in a main window (Form object) and program it to load a URL to the page with your JS code.

Here is an excerpt from MSDN:

*The WebBrowser control also lets you display content that you create in your application or you retrieve from a database or resource file. Use the DocumentText or DocumentStream property to get or set the contents of the current document as a string or data stream.*

You can also manipulate the contents of a Web page through the Document property, which contains an HtmlDocument object that provides managed access to the HTML document object model (DOM) for the current page. This property is useful, when used in combination with the ObjectForScripting property, to implement two-way communication between your (Windows) *application code and dynamic HTML (DHTML) code in a Web page, letting you combine Web-based controls and Windows Forms controls in a single user interface. You can use the Document property to call scripting code methods from your application*(Windows code). *Your scripting code can access your application through the window.external object, which is a built-in DOM object provided for host access, and which maps to the object that you specify for the ObjectForScripting property.*

The WebBrowser control is a managed wrapper for the ActiveX WebBrowser control, and uses whichever version of the control is installed on the user's computer.

Comment: Interesting. Any problems or disadvantages of this option?

Comment: Well, the .NET WebBrowser object doesn't support what IE doesn't; in other words, your application will look like on IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a normal HTML file become a Windows App simply by changing the file's extension into ".hta"

Windows will treat your *.hta file like a winform application. This is called "html application" - HTA.

More documentations herer :

[Html application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And of course, you can attach as much Javascript as you want in that HTA file, or even use external *.js file by doing like this :

```
<script src="your file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your could try something like

[Chromeless](https://mozillalabs.com/chromeless/).

This way, you could keep your code, and it at least would kinda look like a desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adobe.com/products/air/

http://gears.google.com/

So far, i'd go with adobe air since it's portability and robustness (doesn't make it errorless, tho)