# Create a local web application

Tags: web-applications, relative-path

my problem is:

I developed a web application (only html and javascript, it doesn't need any server enviroment like for example PHP interpreter). 
I'd like to make it similar to a desktop application, so I downloaded a portable version of Google Chrome and I created an application shortcut to the local file.
Now the problem is:
the shortcut uses an absolute path but I need a relative path so that the app will work in every Filesystem location.

Could someone help me?
Is there a solution for relative path?
Otherwise is there another solution instead of Chrome application shortcut?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on a microsoft forum:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-to-create-a-shortcut-with-relative-path/3e1b0ede-1e18-4ecd-937b-66756d3409d3

I think that should work for your problem as well.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the question: [Convert Javascript app into Windows app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465820/convert-javascript-app-into-windows-app)

They discuss multiple solutions on there. Two of the ones that looked like something worth trying to me were renaming your main html files to hta or the Chromeless application.